# Cannot access GIT behind firewall for MDB dependencies

Tags: git, ssl, npm, angular-material, angular-cli

Following the documentation as instructed, https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/ (Pro version NPM installation).

I am unable to access the GIT file requested because our company firewall restricts access to the certificate.

Is there a method that could work in my `package.json`?

---

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
...
    "git+https://oauth2:xxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/ng-uikit-pro-standard.git"
},
```

**ERROR for npm install:**

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t https://oauth2:sBBYpBsf-mcbHgYHUFa7@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/ng-uikit-pro-standard.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'https://oauth2:sBBYpBsf-mcbHgYHUFa7@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/ng-uikit-pro-standard.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

Comment: Host `git.mdbootstrap.com` is not using a self signed certificate so if this is what you get it means you are under local TLS DPI and some local system is giving you an alternate certificate instead of the true one. You can use git `sslCAinfo` configuration option to specify which CA to trust, in your case you will need to put there the self signed certificate that you get.

Comment: The only thing I would add to @PatrickMevzek's comment is, I would *not* make a habit of just adding "whatever cert the software is complaining about" to the trust store.  You should probably check with your networking folk to understand what cert(s) *should* be needed for proper operation behind your proxy.